# how to use use labelframe across the buttons

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a widget with labels, entries and buttons.

I wanted to enclose them inside a labelframe, for more meaningful and visual understanding.

I already grid my labels buttons and entries on a widget, now I can't use pack for labelframe. Is there any way I can add labelframe around my entries, buttons and labels?

Excerpt from my code:

```
grid .top.d.f2.a0 -row 3 -column 2 -sticky nsew -padx 2 -pady 2 -ipadx 2 -ipady 2
grid .top.d.f2.a -row 4 -column 2 -sticky nsew -padx 2 -pady 2 -ipadx 2 -ipady 2

grid .top.d.f2.ent1 -row 3 -column 3 -sticky nsew -padx 2 -pady 2 -ipadx 2 -ipady 2
grid .top.d.f2.ent2 -row 4 -column 3 -sticky nsew -padx 2 -pady 2 -ipadx 2 -ipady 2

grid .top.d.f2.b1 -row 3 -column 4 -sticky nsew -padx 2 -pady 2 -ipadx 2 -ipady 2
grid .top.d.f2.b2 -row 4 -column 4 -sticky nsew -padx 2 -pady 2 -ipadx 2 -ipady 2
```

I tried using:

```
set w [labelframe .top.d.f2.lb -text setup_options]
grid $w
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the labelframe first, then fill it with the labels, entries and buttons, so they become children of that widget:

```
set w [labelframe .top.d.f2.lb -text setup_options]
grid $w

# Create the labels, entries and buttons here, for example:
# label $w.a0 -text "Memory List"

grid $w.a0 -row 3 -column 2 -sticky nsew -padx 2 -pady 2 -ipadx 2 -ipady 2
grid $w.a -row 4 -column 2 -sticky nsew -padx 2 -pady 2 -ipadx 2 -ipady 2

grid $w.ent1 -row 3 -column 3 -sticky nsew -padx 2 -pady 2 -ipadx 2 -ipady 2
grid $w.ent2 -row 4 -column 3 -sticky nsew -padx 2 -pady 2 -ipadx 2 -ipady 2

grid $w.b1 -row 3 -column 4 -sticky nsew -padx 2 -pady 2 -ipadx 2 -ipady 2
grid $w.b2 -row 4 -column 4 -sticky nsew -padx 2 -pady 2 -ipadx 2 -ipady 2
```

(untested)

Comment: This is not working for me, throwing bad window Error for children's.

Comment: also needs to modify the names of labels, entries and buttons as slaves and it works well. Thanks Jerry

Comment: @DanishSheikh right, I should have mentioned that as well... oops